# Create lines with gradient color using imagick

Tags: php, laravel, imagemagick, imagick

I have a basic texture and I want to draw multiple lines on that texture image. lines should be drawn randomly on the image at random places. I am able to draw the lines but the color of those lines should in gradient.

The color of the lines should be light from the edges and dark from the center. The code I am using right now is below

```
$draw = new \ImagickDraw();
$draw->setStrokeOpacity(0);
$draw->setStrokeColor('red');
$draw->setStrokeWidth(0);
$draw->setFillColor('red');
$draw->line(10, 30, 380, 30);
$image = new \Imagick();
$image->newImage($width * 3, $height * 2, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');
$image->setImageFormat('png');
$image->drawImage($draw);
```

I want the output to be like the image below

[image: required]

but I can only create like the one below:

[image: required]

The background is the texture image and the lines (orange and green) are the ones that I want to draw on the background (texture image).

I can't find anything in the docs, any help is appreciated

Comment: Please define how exactly you want to make them a gradient. There is no unique draw method/option in ImageMagick that will do what you show directly. But you can draw lines, make a mask for each line and create a solarized gradient of the same size. Then put the solarized gradient into the alpha channel of the line to make the line color fade as it approached the ends. Then composite the line over the image at the place you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do that in ImageMagick command line. You can translate that to Imagick.

**create background image**

```
convert -size 500x500 xc:gray +noise gaussian -channel g -separate +channel background.png
```

[image]

**create 1D red line image with end gradients**

```
convert -size 300x1 xc:red \
\( -size 1x300 gradient: -rotate 90 -solarize 50% -level 0x50% -white-threshold 50% +write grad.png \) \
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite red_grad.png
```

[image]

**place red line image onto background**

```
convert background.png red_grad.png -geometry +100+250 -compose over -composite result.png
```

[image]

You can use other methods other than -white-threshold to adjust the transparency along the red line in the gradient alpha channel.